# Why do Hill and Frost Giants have a bigger damage bonus than their Strength bonus?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

In the D&D 3.5 *Monster Manual*, a [Hill Giant's](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/giant.htm#hillgiant) damage entry shows:

> Greatclub +16 melee (2d8+10)

A Hill Giant's strength bonus is +7. Since there doesn't appear to be any magic abilities or feats that increase the bonus to damage, where does the additional +3 damage come from?

The [Frost Giant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/giant.htm#frostgiant) has the same problem.  Their damage entry shows:

> Greataxe +18/+13 melee (3d6+13/×3)

However, their strength modifier is only +9.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The hill giant and frost giant are both using two-handed weapons (a greatclub and a greataxe, respectively), and a two-handed weapon gets a ×1½ STR bonus for damage. With fractions rounded down, +7 × 1½ is +10, and +9 × 1½ is +13. That's all that's going on.